# Firebase Realtime Database obtain push() reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how I save my Events in my app:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").push().setValue(ev);
```

[image]

Now I would like each event to have its own chat room where users can send messages to each other. However, I need to know the reference to the event so I can add the chat room. I don't want to change the Event object to have this property. How do I do that?

```
databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").child(?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the pushed event using `DatabaseReference#getKey()`, so to retrieve the newly added event, call:

```
String eventId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").push()
                                                                              .getKey()
```

Then you can do:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").child(eventId)...
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.